# TestNG not showing up in preferences- JDK 1.8

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have the JDK 1.8 and still TestNG is not showing up in preferences nor in Run Configurations. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[Run As >> Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fY5U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIiLJ.png)

Comment: show us the POM file please

Comment: Sorry I am not clear abou the POM File, i downloaded the JAr from this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.9.4 

I did not download the POM file, Could you please guide me what should I do here

Comment: Aren't you using maven ? I suggest you start using maven which is a lot more easier then manually downloading the JAR's and importing them.
none the less, go to properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add Library and choose TESTNG

Comment: Thanks...I would have a look into Maven. However, the path you suggested above, TestNG is not visible on clicking Add Library.

Options visible are:
JRE
JUnit
Maven Managed Dependencies
Plug in dependencies
User Lib
xtend lib

Comment: I've always used Maven so wouldn't be sure, check this link http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/05/01/testng-tutorials-2-installation-of-testng-in-eclipse-download-and-add-to-build-path-way/